# Question about polynomial sequences and functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, even-and-odd-functions

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and is even, i.e. $f(x) = f(-x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, suppose $(p_n)$ is a sequence of polynomials converging uniformly to $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$, does it mean that $p_n$ is also even for each $n$? If not, is there a counterexample?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and tell us your thought about the problem :)

Comment: @AirMike , I tried to prove that the coefficients of Pn converges to the corresponding coefficients of f, but I am not sure how to prove that the sequence is also even or not

Comment: There are trivial counterexamples as you can change the first finitely many terms of the sequence to anything you want and have it still converge uniformly. A more interesting question is whether the polynomials are eventually even.

Comment: In that case the answer is yes. In fact, a sequence of polynomials converging uniformly on $\mathbb R$ is a very strict condition. It implies that $f$ is a polynomial and eventually all that is changing in the sequence is the constant term.

Comment: @MattSamuel I am confused, because I thought that the sequence can not converge to the function on R unless they are constant

Comment: @MattSamuel and if there is counterexamples for x on the subset of R, is it sufficient to say that the statement is false?

Comment: @LeiYu A sequence of distinct polynomials can converge uniformly on $\mathbb R$. For example, $f_n(x)=x+1/n$ converges uniformly to $f(x)=x$. It's just that eventually they're all basically the same polynomial, possibly shifted by a constant. As I said, there are trivial counterexamples to your literal question, which is why I wasn't sure if that was actually the question you wanted to ask.

Comment: @MattSamuel so, take your example, make Pn = x + x/n + 1/n, then Pn also converges uniformly to f on R? but not even for each n.

Comment: @LeiYu $P_n(x) = x+x/n+1/n$ doesn't converge uniformly to anything. $P_n(x)-P_{n+1}(x)$ is always unbounded. But the limit function isn't even anyway. If we did $P_n(x)=x^2+1/n$, this converges uniformly and all of the elements in the sequence are even. We could make the first term $x$ and then they aren't all even, but eventually they all are. They always will be if the limit is even, because the only coefficient that can change for all but finitely many terms is the constant term.

Comment: Also, you made the same mistake as the other user did ... Or was it you ?

Comment: @MattSamuel so, it means that when n gets big enough, they basically become the same polynomial, while for small n's, we can alter the first finitely many terms to make it not even?

Comment: @LeiYu Yes, that's right.

Comment: @MattSamuel Thank you!

Comment: @nicomezi why does pn+x/n converges uniformly? and will it make any differences if its on R instead of some closed intervals?

Comment: @nicomezi As stated in the rebuttal comment I added, that is false, but close to true. Sequences of nonconstant polynomials can converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$, but for large enough $n$ all coefficients are the same for each successive term except possibly the constant term.

Comment: Indeed, I was obsessed about considering non polynomial functions as limits. @MattSamuel